# jquery file upload validation not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

As FormData() is not supported in IE8, I decided to give jQuery File Upload a shot in my ASP web app, which seems to work in IE8, however it's not performing according to how I planned.

I'm using the latest version (I updated yesterday) of the library taken from: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I have the following file references in a script bundle

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-file-upload/jquery.ui.widget.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload-process.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"
```

I also use a Twitter Bootstrap theme and Knockout. The following function is triggered when the button to open the modal is clicked, to initialise the library to the form in the modal.

```
registerFileUpload: =>
    $("#target-form").fileupload(
        add: (e, data) =>
            data.context = $("#save-target-btn").click( ->
                data.submit()
            )
        done: (e, data) =>
            $("#add-new-target-modal").modal('hide')
        type: "POST"
        multipart: true
        url: "/route/to/save"
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(csv)$/i
    )
    .on('fileuploadadd', (e, data) ->
        appendTarget = $("#add-new-target-modal .modal-body")
        $.each(data.files, (index, file) ->
            $("#add-new-target-modal .modal-body").append("<span>" + file.name + "</span>");
        )
    )
```

My issue is that maxNumberOfFiles and acceptFileTypes don't seem to be used properly i.e. I can still select multiple files to upload (I can select 2 files and it will upload them as separate requests) and of any file format (I can select a file with .txt extension) ?

Basically, I only want the user to only be able to upload 1 file which is a .csv.